# SQL Server - Special characters not recognise by PHP (ODBC)

Tags: php, sql-server, odbc

I am trying to display some information from SQL Server to my PHP site. I am using ODBC connection for that one.

My Issue is : Special characters are not recognised and it is displaying "question mark (?)" in my site. (This works in my other ASP site)

What I am missing here ? Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use some special MSSQL query converter and then ICONV in the PHP side like this:

```
   SELECT  CAST(Remarks AS TEXT) Remarks FROM r_table;
```

And in the PHP, say the text is in CodePage 1255:

```
   iconv('CP1255', 'UTF-8', $remark);
```

hope that's helps.

Answer (score 0):

What's your character encoding for the ODBC connection?
It should be some UTF with proper handling on PHP side...

Comment: Hi, I am not using any UTF encoding for now. Below is my code...



function get_odbc_connection()
{
 $myServer = "Driver={SQL Server};Server={server_ip_address};Database={database_name}";
 $myUser   = "{username}";
 $myPass   = "{pwd}";
 $myDB     = "{database_name}"; 
 
 // create connection 
 $connection = odbc_connect($myServer,$myUser,$myPass,SQL_CUR_USE_ODBC); 
 
 // test connection 
 if (!$connection) { 
  echo "Couldn't make a connection!"; 
  exit; 
 } 
 else
 {  
  return $connection;
 }
}